# Matplotlib step function: How to extend the first and last steps

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using a `step` and `fill_between` functions in Matplotlib and want the steps to be centred on the x points.

#### Code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

xpoints=np.array([1,2,3,4])
ypoints=np.array([4,6,5,2])
ypoints_std=np.array([0.5,0.3,0.4,0.2])
plt.step(xpoints,ypoints,where='mid')
plt.fill_between(xpoints,ypoints+ypoints_std,ypoints-ypoints_std,step='mid',alpha=0.2)
plt.show()
```

Current plot:

[image]

At the moment, the step centred on 1 is only 0.5 wide, whereas the step centred on 2 is 1 wide.

#### Wanted

I actually want the step-width of 1 for all steps and also for the fill. This should include first and last step, so that they are extended compared to the current plot.

[image]

Of course I can pad the data, but that is getting messy in my actual code.

#### Questions

1. Is there a way to make the first and last steps the same size as the middle ones?
2. Or is there a way to produce a similar graph using histogram ? i.e. showing an error the size of the full width of the bar, centred on the y position of the graph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Using a bar plot at a height

The error bands could be shown via a bar plot with a bottom at `ypoints - ypoints_std` and a height of `2*ypoints_std`.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

xpoints = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
ypoints = np.array([4, 6, 5, 2])
ypoints_std = np.array([0.5, 0.3, 0.4, 0.2])

plt.bar(xpoints, ypoints, width=1, facecolor='none', edgecolor='dodgerblue')
plt.bar(xpoints, height=2 * ypoints_std, bottom=ypoints - ypoints_std, width=1, color='dodgerblue', alpha=0.2)

plt.xticks(xpoints)
plt.show()
```

[image: using plt.bar to show error bands]

## Using zero-height bars

To only have horizontal lines, you could replace the first bar plot with zero-height bars.  Adding the original `plt.step` with the same color will create the connecting lines

```py
plt.gca().use_sticky_edges = False # prevent bars from "sticking" to the bottom
plt.step(xpoints, ypoints, where='mid', color='dodgerblue')
plt.bar(xpoints, height=0, bottom=ypoints, width=1, facecolor='none', edgecolor='dodgerblue')
plt.bar(xpoints, height=2 * ypoints_std, bottom=ypoints - ypoints_std, width=1, color='dodgerblue', alpha=0.2)
```

[image: combining zero-height bars with step plot]

## Extending the points

You could add dummy values to repeat the first and last point. And then use `plt.xlim(...)` to limit the plot between `0.5` and `4.5`.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

xpoints = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
ypoints = np.array([4, 6, 5, 2])
ypoints_std = np.array([0.5, 0.3, 0.4, 0.2])

xpoints = np.concatenate([[xpoints[0] - 1], xpoints, [xpoints[-1] + 1]])
ypoints = np.pad(ypoints, 1, mode='edge')
ypoints_std = np.pad(ypoints_std, 1, mode='edge')

plt.step(xpoints, ypoints, where='mid')
plt.fill_between(xpoints, ypoints + ypoints_std, ypoints - ypoints_std, step='mid', alpha=0.2)
plt.xlim(xpoints[0] + 0.5, xpoints[-1] - 0.5)
plt.show()
```

[image: extending step where='mid']

Comment: Thanks, this is what I'm doing at the moment, but I actually want to plot a number of graphs over the top of each other with some at half widths, so the code is getting very messy!

Comment: Does the approach zero-height bars work better for you? You could plot these on top of the `plt.step` using the same colors.

Comment: That's perfect, thank you very much! I was looking for something like the 'bottom' argument in plt.hist, but plt.bar is much better. You've reduced my 50 lines of code (still not right!) to 6, I'm very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`pyplot.margins(0)`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.margins.html) to at least let your graph touch the axis on all 4 sides (left/right and bottom/top).

Either use two positional arguments for x and y, or use one to be applied for both:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

xpoints=np.array([1,2,3,4])
ypoints=np.array([4,6,5,2])
ypoints_std=np.array([0.5,0.3,0.4,0.2])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.step(xpoints,ypoints,where='mid')
ax.fill_between(xpoints,ypoints+ypoints_std,ypoints-ypoints_std,step='mid',alpha=0.2)
ax.margins(0)  # default margins are 0.5 for x-axis and y-axis

plt.show()
```

Output:

[image: plot with zero margins]